# plugin:vite:css sass Undefined variable vue 3

Tags: vue.js, sass

I have created a vue 3 application with vite , i want to use sass in my project , I have a problem accessing any variable I have created in my scss files

I have installed sass and sass loader , this is my package.json

```
"devDependencies": {
    "sass": "^1.63.6",
    "sass-loader": "^10.1.1",
    "typescript": "^5.0.2",
    "vite": "^4.4.0",
    "vue-tsc": "^1.8.3"
  }
```

this is the files structure I have created inside src[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOGJL.png)

then I have imported the style.scss inside the App.vue , when i try to access a variable inside _colors.scss
the following error rises [plugin:vite:css] [sass] Undefined variable vue 3
any help ?